# running curl in a for loop blocks access to website

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have the following code which basically runs a bunch of curl request in a for loop
This is a background system job.. however when this code is running.. i can't access the website, website is just loading until this task/function is finished

```
public function endcount() {

        $order_list = $this->order_model->get_rows([
            'where' => [
              "status IN ('Processing', 'In Progress') AND service_id = 1"
            ],
            'order_by' => 'quantity ASC',
            'limit' => '200'
        ]);

    
        
        foreach ($order_list as $key => $value) {

            $start_count = $value['start_count'];
            
            
            //service id = 1 is for followers
            if ($value['service_id'] == '1' || $value['service_id'] == '3' || $value['service_id'] == '5') {
                
                

                $end_count = 0;

                
                try {
                    

            
                    $username = $value['target'];
                    $proxy = '139.99.54.49:10163';
                    $proxyauth = 'username:password';

                    $url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'. $username .'/?__a=1&__d=dis';
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);     // PROXY details with port
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);   // Use if proxy have username and password
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json') );
                    $data = curl_exec($ch);
                    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                        $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
                        var_dump($error_msg);
                    }

                    $json_data = json_decode($data, true);
                    if ($json_data && array_key_exists('graphql', $json_data)) {
                        $end_count = $json_data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
                    } else {
                        var_dump($username . ' data ga bisa');
                        $end_count = 0;
                    }
                    

                    curl_close($ch);


                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getMessage());
                    $end_count = 0;
                }

                if ($end_count == -666) {
                    $end_count = $start_count + 5;
                }
                

                $total_followers = $start_count + $value['quantity'];
                $remains = $total_followers - $end_count;

                if ($remains <= 10) {
                    $status = 'Success';
                } else {
                    $status = 'Partial';
                }

            
                var_dump('end count of ' . $value['target'] . ' ' . $end_count . ' WITH REMAINS: ' . $remains);

                if ($status == 'Success') {
                    $update_order = [
                    'remains' => $remains,
                    'status' => $status,
                    'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    ];
                    $update_order = $this->order_model->update($update_order, ['id' => $value['id']]);
                    if ($update_order == true) {
                        print('ID '.$value['id'].' => ['.$status.'] - [FINAL COUNT : '.$end_count.'] - [REMAINS : '.$remains.'] - [TARGET COUNT : '.$total_followers.']<br>');
                    } else {
                        print('Error..');
                    }
                }
                
                //var_dump($value['target']);
            } else if ($value['service_id'] == '2') {
                //service id = 2 is for likers

            }
            
        }
        
}
```

is there any way i can optimize this code so it is not blocking access to the site while running ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding sleep(5); funtion to your code so server isn't overloaded with requests..

your code should look something like this :

```
 foreach ($order_list as $key => $value) {

        sleep(5);

        $start_count = $value['start_count'];
```